# create xml data polygon via php from database mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml

iam attempting to create XML data polygon via php from database mysql, my xml result only one data polygon, even though mysql database have many data polygon. please help me how i solve it.

```
this is my results xml :
<bangunan><titik bujur="108.1052017828" lintang="-6.8589564633"/><titik bujur=" 108.1052345542" lintang="-6.8588736944"/><titik bujur=" 108.1052901005" lintang="-6.8588919206"/><titik bujur=" 108.1053264106" lintang="-6.8587653305"/><titik bujur=" 108.1052012876" lintang="-6.8587287935"/><titik bujur=" 108.1051327105" lintang="-6.8589320607"/><titik bujur=" 108.1051327105" lintang="-6.8589320607"/><titik bujur=" 108.1052017828" lintang="-6.8589564633"/><titik bujur=" 108.1052017828" lintang="-6.8589564633"/></bangunan>
```

[and that is my database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR6o0.png)

and this is my code:

```
<?php
include "koneksibangunan.php";
$x=mysql_query("select * from bangunan");
$y=mysql_fetch_array($x);
$id=$y['ID'];
$nama=$y['Nama'];
$batas=$y['Koordinat'];
$urai=explode(',0',$batas);
$max=count($urai)-1;

//konversi ke array 2 D, menghasilkan $koor[i][j]
for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<2;$j++)
    {
        $koor[$i]=explode(',',$urai[$i]);
}}
//konversi ke format XML
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo '<bangunan>';
for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++)
{
 echo '<titik ';
    for($j=0;$j<2;$j++)
    {
        if($j==1)
            echo 'lintang="' .$koor[$i][$j]. '" ';
        else
         echo 'bujur="' . $koor[$i][$j] . '" ';
    }
   echo '/>';
    }
echo '</bangunan>';
```

Comment: Can you show your code so far (also please include the data as text and not images)

Comment: <bangunan><titik bujur="108.1052017828" lintang="-6.8589564633"/><titik bujur=" 108.1052345542" lintang="-6.8588736944"/><titik bujur=" 108.1052901005" lintang="-6.8588919206"/><titik bujur=" 108.1053264106" lintang="-6.8587653305"/><titik bujur=" 108.1052012876" lintang="-6.8587287935"/><titik bujur=" 108.1051327105" lintang="-6.8589320607"/><titik bujur=" 108.1051327105" lintang="-6.8589320607"/><titik bujur=" 108.1052017828" lintang="-6.8589564633"/><titik bujur=" 108.1052017828" lintang="-6.8589564633"/></bangunan>

Comment: that is my xml result

Comment: And your code is?

Comment: i have edited on my question above

Comment: You are only fetching the first row from the database (`mysql_fetch_array` only fetches a single row) and so you need to create a look while this returns data - `while ($y = mysql_fetch_array($result)){`

Comment: while ($y = mysql_fetch_array($x)){ 
$id=$y['ID'];
$nama=$y['Nama'];
$batas=$y['Koordinat'];
$urai=explode(',0',$batas);
$max=count($urai)-1;
}

Comment: do you mean like above??

Comment: but the result is only last row..

Answer (score 0):

The code needs to loop over every row, so when you do a select, read each row and process the content...

```
<?php
include "koneksibangunan.php";
$x=mysql_query("select * from bangunan");
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo '<data>';
while($y=mysql_fetch_array($x))  {
    $id=$y['ID'];
    $nama=$y['Nama'];
    $batas=$y['Koordinat'];
    $urai=explode(',0',$batas);
    $max=count($urai)-1;

    //konversi ke array 2 D, menghasilkan $koor[i][j]
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++)    {
        for($j=0;$j<2;$j++)    {
            $koor[$i]=explode(',',$urai[$i]);
        }
    }
    //konversi ke format XML
    echo '<bangunan>';
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++)    {
        echo '<titik ';
        for($j=0;$j<2;$j++)    {
            if($j==1)
                echo 'lintang="' .$koor[$i][$j]. '" ';
            else
                echo 'bujur="' . $koor[$i][$j] . '" ';
        }
        echo '/>';
    }
    echo '</bangunan>';
}
echo '</data>';
```

It's difficult to test, but I hope you see that the output has to be under an overall element ( - change as required).  It may be that everything is under , if so just move this to where I have included the  bit.

Comment: @nafis good to here that!  Could you mark as correct answer as it makes it easier to see what questions haven't been solved.  Thanks